# Can I save the selection from a drop-down list and set it as the default value for the next app start?

Tags: java, android

there is a drop-down menu with a custom listView in my app. The data in this listView comes from an arraylist (one image and 2 strings for each entry). When the user selects an option from this list, it shows the image and the first string value in an imageview and a textview - see picture below.

[Listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkzue.png)

[After selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhuke.png)

Now I want the selection by the user to be saved and automatically loaded and displayed upon the next app start.
Here is my code for opening the list and selecting an option:

```
fromDropDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fromDialog = new Dialog(ActivityMain.this);
            fromDialog.setContentView(R.layout.from_spinner);
            fromDialog.getWindow().setLayout(MATCH_PARENT,1200);
            fromDialog.show();


            EditText editText = fromDialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
            ListView listView = fromDialog.findViewById(R.id.list_view);


            JavaAdapter javaAdapter = new JavaAdapter(ActivityMain.this,R.layout.list_row,arrayList);
            listView.setAdapter(javaAdapter);


            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count) {
                    javaAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    fromDropDown.setText(javaAdapter.getItem(position).getExample());
                    picLeft.setImageResource(javaAdapter.getItem(position).getImage());
                    fromDialog.dismiss();
                }

            });
        }
    });
```

Right now I set the "default" value for the first start by doing this:

```
fromDropDown.setText(javaAdapter.getItem(0).getExample());
    picLeft.setImageResource(javaAdapter.getItem(0).getImage());
```

But after the user selects an option, I want the app to save that selection and display this new selection on the next app start instead of my "default" value.
This presumably works with sharedpreferences, but I can't figure it out... Maybe someone can give me a hint in the right direction how this could be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save in shared preferences the position of selected item, and instead to set by default 0 you to this one:

save position

```
val sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("APP_SHARED", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        with(sharedPref.edit()) {
            putInt("position", selectedPosition).apply()
        }
///after application loaded
val sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("APP_SHARED",Context.MODE_PRIVATE) 
val position = sharedPref.getInt("position", 0) //0 default value in case when nothing was setted

fromDropDown.setText(javaAdapter.getItem(position).getExample());
picLeft.setImageResource(javaAdapter.getItem(position).getImage());
```

Comment: This looks very promising! But ist this Kotlin?
Sorry, I'm pretty new and I am just about to learn some Java... What would that look like in Java code?

Comment: not, this is kotlin\